# SQL job calling ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I am getting below error when running a sql job that calls SSIS package. Does anyone know what is the issue?
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object : at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISSerrverExecution.Events.LoadPackage(PackageItem item) at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ProjectOperator.StartPackage() at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.Project(Operator.PerformOperation()"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like that the user you run SSIS package in SQL SERVER not have permission to Run the job you can use credential like this then test again
[SSIS Package Credentials](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ssis-package-credentials)